# Are Groups as referred to in the Fogbugz Web UI the same as Discussion Groups as referred to in the FogBugz-API?

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

Are Groups as referred to in the Fogbugz Web UI the same as [Discussion Groups](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/fogbugz-xml-api) *(CTRL+F "Discussion Groups")* as referred to in the FogBugz-API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The "Groups" in the Web UI refer to permissions.